# Unable to click on menu dropdown on a JSP page using selenium JAVA testcase

Tags: java, selenium, jsp, automated-tests, selenium-ide

Below is the jsp page. In the left frame i have an clickable item called as "Replication management"

Below is my "View Source"of the JSP main parent page opened by the driver.

```
<!-- Mark the file as a JSP and set up the classes to import -->


<HEAD>
<link rel="icon" href="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/tds-16.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/tds-16.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</HEAD>



<HTML dir='ltr'>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>
IBM Security Directory Server Web Administration Tool
</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<FRAMESET ROWS="40,*">


<FRAME SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSBannerFrame.jsp" TITLE="Banner Frame" NAME="BannerFrame" MARGINWIDTH="1" MARGINHEIGHT="1" SCROLLING="NO" NORESIZE FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">

<FRAMESET COLS="20%,80%">

<FRAME SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp" TITLE="Navigation frame" NAME="NavFrame" MARGINWIDTH="1" MARGINHEIGHT="1" SCROLLING="AUTOMATIC" FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">

<FRAME SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSWorkFrame.jsp" TITLE="Work Area Frameset" NAME="WorkArea" MARGINWIDTH="1" MARGINHEIGHT="1" SCROLLING="AUTOMATIC" FRAMEBORDER="1" FRAMESPACING="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">

<NOFRAMES>
<BODY>
The IBM Security Directory Server Web Administration Tool does not currently support Web browsers that do not support frames. Contact the Directory Server administrator to find a Web browser that supports frames.
</BODY>
</NOFRAMES>

</FRAMESET>

<NOFRAMES>
<BODY>
The IBM Security Directory Server Web Administration Tool does not currently support Web browsers that do not support frames. Contact the Directory Server administrator to find a Web browser that supports frames.
</BODY>
</NOFRAMES>

</FRAMESET>

</HTML>
```

Recording testcase in Katalon-Selenium IDE browser plugin gives me the below java code for the click action

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Directory management'])[1]/following::font[1]")).click();
```

However, replaying the test-case does not invoke the "Replication Management" link which drops down to show other clickable items once clicked.

I did right-click on the "Replication Management" link and got "Copy link address" which gave me the below link:

http://myhost:12222/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsreplication#spot

Only the relevant View Source of IDSNavFrame.jsp for clickable item Replication management is below:

```
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idssrvadm#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Server administration" alt="Click here to open Server administration" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Server administration" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Server administration</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsproxy#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Proxy administration" alt="Click here to open Proxy administration" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Proxy administration" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Proxy administration</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsdmt#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Schema management" alt="Click here to open Schema management" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Schema management" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Schema management</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?opennav=idsdirmgmt#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Directory management" alt="Click here to open Directory management" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderClosed.gif" title="Click here to open Directory management" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Directory management</Font></A></td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navHeading">
<a name="spot"></a>
<A HREF="/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/IDSNavFrame.jsp?closenav=idsreplication#spot" BORDERCOLOR="#000000"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnTnOpened.gif" title="Click here to close Replication management" alt="Click here to close Replication management" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/WnFolderOpen.gif" title="Click here to close Replication management" alt="" align="texttop" border="0" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="16"><IMG SRC="/IDSWebApp/IDSgui/Blank.gif" alt="" border="0" align="texttop" HEIGHT="16" WIDTH="2"><Font size="2" color="#454589" face="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Replication management</Font></A>
</td></tr>
<tr><td nowrap class="navTask">
```

The drop-down should have another clickable item called: http://myhost:12222/IDSWebApp/IDSRunTask?task-name=managequeues which should also be invoked.

Can someone please suggest the Java code to invoke the two links ?

Comment: It looks like elements are available inside nested frame.you need to switch to frame first in order to access the element.can you share us the url as well to ensure.

Comment: It's a private url but i have shared the entire view source of the url so one can create a similar page structure locally.